# DocuSign Envelope Fields - status_changed_date_time and last_modified_date_time - Webhooks Response

Tags: docusignapi

We are using the DocuSign SDK (version 3.3.0) and utilizing webhooks to receive the various envelope and recipient events.

In the envelope, I need to retrieve the fields (**status_changed_date_time** and **last_modified_date_time**) in the XML message from the DocuSign Connect. But I identified that those fields are not being sent in the XML message.

Is there any way to include those above mentioned fields in the XML message from DocuSign connect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XML notification body is what it is. If it doesn't include the data your application needs, then make additional API calls to DocuSign to obtain the data you want. Doing so is a common pattern.

Note: It is important that you respond to DocuSign with a 200 status right away--all your processing should be done asynchronously on a different thread. Don't delay your 200 response.